# Type trait for trivial types

Tags: c++, type-traits

I would like to have a type trait that returns true for any type which does not need memory to be initialised before being used and whose copy constructor can be implemented as a memcpy.

I want it to return true for

- integer types (char, short int, int, long int, etc)
- floating point number types (float, double)
- il::array (il::array is my own implementation of std::array) for T being one of int, double, il::array, etc.

and false for thing such as std::vector, and any object that needs something at construction (most objects).

std::is_pod seems to be quite close to what I want as it also returns true for std::array, but unfortunately it does not return true for my own il::array. Is there any way to "teach" is_pod that my il::array behaves as plain old data, or an easy way to roll out my own type trait?

For information, here is my implementation of il::array:

```
namespace il {

template <typename T, int n>
class array {
private:
    T data_[n > 0 ? n : 1];
public:
    array(const T& value)
            : array() {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            data_[k] = value;
        }
    }
    array(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
        IL_ASSERT(n == static_cast<int>(list.size()));
        for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
            data_[k] = *(list.begin() + k);
        }
    }
    const T& operator[](int k) const {
        IL_ASSERT(static_cast<unsigned int>(k) < static_cast<unsigned int>(n));
        return data_[k];
    }
    T& operator[](int k) {
        IL_ASSERT(static_cast<unsigned int>(k) < static_cast<unsigned int>(n));
        return data_[k];
    }
    T* data() {
        return data_;
    }
    int size() const {
        return n;
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have a type trait that returns true for any type which does not need memory to be initialised before being used and whose copy constructor can be implemented as a `memcpy`.

You're describing a *trivial type*. You can check for that with [`std::is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial).

> `std::is_pod` seems to be quite close to what I want

That also requires the type to have *standard layout*, which places restrictions on how and where its data members are declared.

> unfortunately it does not return true for my own `il::array`

Perhaps that's not standard layout, in which case `is_trivial` should work for you. Or perhaps it's not actually trivial in any case; in which case, you might want to fix it so that it is.

**UPDATE**: It has a user-declared default constructor, which makes it non-trivial. Since it does nothing but check the value of a compile-time constant, you could replace it with a `static_assert`; or change `n` to a more sensible unsigned type like `std::size_t` to remove the need for the sanity check.

But you'll still need to declare it as defaulted

```
array() = default;
```

otherwise the presence of the other constructors will delete it.

> Is there any way to "teach" `is_pod` that my `il::array` behaves as plain old data?

You could write your own trait, with a specialisation for your type. But that would be weird; if your type is supposed to be trivial or POD, then make it so.

Comment: It turns out that std::is_trivial<il::array<double, 2>>::value is false and I want it to be true. By the way std::is_trivial<std::array<double, 2>>::value is true. My il::array is almost the same as std::array.

Comment: @InsideLoop: In that case, you've done something to make it non-trivial; either declared a default, copy or move constructor, or given it a non-trivial data member or base class.

Comment: Mike. I have posted my implementation of il::array. I don't understand what makes it non-trivial for il::array<double, 2>.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Now you've posted the code, we can see there's a non-trivial default constructor. You'll need to remove that to make it trivial. You could replace it with a `static_assert` if you want to keep the sanity check. Or it might be more sensible to make `n` unsigned.

Comment: Removing the default constructor does not make any difference (I have edited the post to remove it). Concerning unsigned int, I want to keep away from them as it was a mistake to use them as indices in the STL (acknowledged by Bjarne Stroustrup, Scott Meyer, Herb Sutter, etc). This is one of the many reason I have implemented my own std::vector and std::array.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Declaring the other constuctors removes the default constructor, so it's not trivially constructible. `array() = default;` should fix it.

Comment: array() = default fixes the problem. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Specializing a standard library type trait, with one exception (`std::common_type` for user-defined types), is UB.

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks, I didn't know that. I've removed that dodgy suggestion.